# What is $10^{40}$ as a number?

Tags: index-notation

What is $10^{40}$?

Every time I google this question I get $1\mathrm{e}\!+\!40$ but I don’t understand this so what is it as a number?

Comment: What are you asking?  It is $1$ followed by $40$ zeroes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you know that for any real number $a$ and whole number $n$, $a^n$ is the product of $n$ factors of $a$:
$$
    a^n = \underbrace{a \cdot a \cdots a}_{\text{$n$ factors}}
$$
So $10^{40}$ is the product of forty tens, all in a row.

In our base-ten system, multiplying by ten has the effect of adding a zero to the end of the number.  So $10^{40} = 10 \times 10^{39}$ is $10$ followed by $39$ zeroes.  In other words, $1$ followed by forty zeroes.

This is useful in [scientific notation](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).  It's a way to conveniently express very large or very small numbers without writing a lot of zeroes.  For instance, the number $1234500000$ can be written as $1.2345 \times 10^9$.  A calculator or computer expresses scientific notation with the letter `e` for “exponent” (of the base 10).  So $1.2345 \times 10^9$ gets printed as `1.2345e+9`.

Comment: I've given +1 for the full explanation. I'd suggest adding a note on notation $1.2345\mathrm{e}\!+\!9$ as well.

Comment: @Ennar good suggestion.  I've edited.

Answer (score 2):

This is $$10^{40}=10000000000000000000000000000000000000000$$

Answer (score 1):

... or ten thousand trillion trillion trillion (where 1 trillion = $10^{12}$) or, even shorter, ten duodecillion.

Comment: Or even shorter, $10^{40}$, which is why we use the notation!

Answer (score 0):

OK,
$10^{39}$ is called [one Duodecillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers)

hence:

> $10^{40}$ is *ten Duodecillion*